# Can Dark Elixir be stored without a storage facility

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm a town hall level 5 and on one of my raids I've taken 120k resources each and I noticed that I got 200 dark elixir, but I don't have dark elixir storage.

Where does it go? When I get a dark elixir storage will i start with 200? or does it all go to waste?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it goes to waste, happend to me at town hall 6. You need a storage to hold it and use it in the future.

Comment: Dont worry about it, dark elixir isn't hard to get, if you're just starting out with your DE storage, use lightning spells to steal DE

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do so upgrade to town hall level 7 and start collecting 600 000 elixer and upgrade elixer storages to level 7 and 9